# Payment method instructions not changing

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, payment-methods, magento-community

I am using Magento 1.7. I am not the original developer of the website, that's why I don't know how everything was configured.

I want to change the instructions of the payment method bank transfer. I found that they are defined in `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment methods -> Bank Transfer Payment -> Instructions`. I also saw that the templated being used is `banktransfer.phtml`, under `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/info`).

However, I changed the text in the Admin and I don't see any change in the frontend. I already cleared Magento's and browser's cache.

Any ideas on what I am missing or doing wrong? Thank you.

**Edit** After the discussion with @Sunil Patel, I couldn't manage to find what was happening. Instead, I commented the code responsible for printing the text, in banktransfer.phtml, and I included the following line, which finally worked fine:

```
        <td><?php echo $instructionsBankTransfer = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/banktransfer/instructions'); ?></td>
```

Comment: please check store wise.

Comment: I already checked all the configuration scopes and changed the text in all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already in backend then may be it will added static into file.

default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml

check above file into your theme.

Or check

app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Banktransfer.php
may be it will overwrite into 
app\code\local\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Banktransfer.php

check function

```
 public function getInstructions()
    {
        return trim($this->getConfigData('instructions'));
    }
```

Also check in core_config_data if you did find any thing

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However I didn't find the text in the file that you mention. There is a bunch of php there but not my text. Maybe one of the PHP functions is retrieving the text? Any other ideas of where it can be located? Thank you.

Comment: Updated code plz check

Comment: @LeCodeur have you checked?

Comment: I just checked and did not find any hardcoded text. The function getConfigData() seems to be defined in `Abstract.php` under `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/` and the code is                              if (null === $storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->getStore();
        }
        $path = 'payment/'.$this->getCode().'/'.$field;
        return Mage::getStoreConfig($path, $storeId);

Comment: but you can in that function which value get it. it is final function you just need to debug.

Comment: I commented the code inside getInstructions() in Banktransfer.php, cleared cache, but the text is still showing. There is only one Banktransfer.php in my store, the one in the core folder. I don't see any in local or community folder. Which other way do I have to debug? I also tried with echo in getConfigData in Abstract.php, but I didn't see any changes. I am not sure if this is the proper way to do things, I am new in PHP, Magento and web developing. Could you kindly tell me if there is a better way to proceed? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: make sure compilation mode disabled.

Comment: Finally the function being used, getInstructions, is the one defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Banktransfer.php`. I did var_dump($this->getInfo()) and see that indeed, the wrong text is inside this info. But I don't know where this 'info' is coming from, how it is defined, how can I change it?

Comment: plz check in core_config_data that text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62205/discussion-between-sunil-patel-and-lecodeur).